# How to convert formatted text in a Powerpoint table cell to HTML

Tags: vba, microsoft-powerpoint

I want to convert a table in a Powerpoint slide to HTML. I know how to put in the table tags, but cannot work out how to convert formatted text inside the table cells to HTML. So, for example, how can I convert "This is a cell with **bold** text" to "This is a cell with <b>bold</b> text"?

I need to be able to this for bold, italicised and colored text (and, ideally, font size and font family). I don't actually want to change the Powerpoint table cell itself, but simply assemble an html string that I will save in a *json* object.

I know how to do this in Word by setting a *Word.range* and using the *Find* method. But I have not been able to replicate this in Powerpoint.

Comment: Why not just export as html?

Comment: @David. It's complicated but I need the html string to use in a json file that allows me to create an interactive slideshow based on the original Powerpoint slides. The vba ppSaveAsHTML and ppSaveAsWebArchive did not produce anything that I could deconstruct.

Comment: @David. Thanks to your comment, I have edited the question to make it clear how I want to use the HTML string.

Comment: This may actually get a better audience at stackoverflow. Wish I could help, but I can't +1

Comment: Raystafarian's correct:  StackOverflow's a better audience.  And FWIW, as of PPT 2010, PPT no longer exports to HTML via the UI (though you can call the EXPORT method from VBA; in 2013, even that's gone).  Quick answer is that each TextRange has a Runs collection. If all of the text in the range is identically formatted, there'll be only one Run in the collection.  If the font/size/color/boldness changes midstream, the Runs collection will be incremented.  Accessing each Run in the collection gives you a TextRange whose font properties you can examine.

Comment: @Steve. Many thanks, I was able to accomplish what I wanted using your suggestion. If you write it up as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each TextRange has a Runs collection. If all of the text in the range is identically formatted, there'll be only one Run in the collection.

If the font/size/color/boldness changes midstream, the Runs collection will be incremented.

Accessing each Run in the collection gives you a TextRange whose font properties you can examine.  Assume for example that you have text like so (all in one shape)

This text is all formatted the same.
This text includes a bit of **bolded** text.

```
Sub thing()

Dim oSh As Shape
Dim oRng As TextRange
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long

' Assume that the shape with your text is selected
Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

' You can look at the text in the shape as a whole,
' or paragraph by paragraph or line by line or character by character.
' Let's do it para by para

With oSh.TextFrame.TextRange
    For x = 1 To .Paragraphs.Count

        With .Paragraphs(x)
            Debug.Print "Paragraph: " & x
            For y = 1 To .Runs.Count
                Debug.Print vbTab & "Run: " & y
                Debug.Print .Runs(y).Font.Bold
            Next
        End With
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Paragraph: 1
    Run: 1
 0 
Paragraph: 2
    Run: 1
 0 
    Run: 2
-1 
    Run: 3
 0

The first paragraph has 1 run only because all the text is formatted the same.
0 = NOT bolded.

The second paragraph has 3 runs (one for each character that's formatted differently from the previous character).  NotBold, BOLD, NotBold